# I can't PING to my Cisco router when I try to access the domain server

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, cisco, domain-controller, ping

I have this network [image](https://file:///C:/Users/pro/Pictures/Capture.PNG)

I tried to connect the pc1 to the domain (in Windows Server 2012).

To do that I tried to PING from pc1 to the server and that works.

After that I go the pc1(Windows 7) and I change it from workgroup to domain, I inserted the domain name and then I entered the username and password for the server, and here the problem started.

After that change  I tried to PING  from pc1 to R1 and server, and it did not work
[image: image2]

for more information:

-pc1
[image: image3]

-server[image: img4]

Can anyone explain what is the cause of this error, and how to fix it?

Comment: you should consider to upload your pictures. your local system drive is not a valid source for it ;)

Comment: i need 10 reputation for be able to upload pictures

Comment: Upload pics some public share website. Check this https://www.itechtics.com/change-network-type-windows-10

Comment: hi, you can use imgurl site to link it in here. it is stated in the formatting help